# Since there are actually Trolls in Shadowrun, is there another word used for "Trolling" a forum?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, sr4-matrix

I didn't even think about the racist meaning of "Troll" when replying to someone who was [Trolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_%28Internet%29) my forum.  I remember some Shadowrun Glossaries, but I'm trying to come up with some "in period" slander that I could use to describe the current day Internet Troll in the 2060's trix...

Comment: PC appeasement of trolls is just lame... No offense meant to those who have suffered crippling injuries.

Answer (score 17):

I suspect that trolling would still be around in the 6th world--at least for us old timers.

UGE only started for elves and dwarves in 2011 (this year) and magic wasn't strong enough to change orks and trolls until 2021. So trolling, as an expression has another 10 years to set itself into the collective conscious.

For the younger set I would probably use drekking forums--or see what your PCs come up with. You can use the here and now on the usage of gay for a template.

And it is a completely different "trolling" that is going on--with more do to with fishing than racism.

Comment: Solid, well reasoned answer. +1

Comment: hmm i always thought "trolling" was more of the under the bridge kind.

Comment: I think its doubling up that makes it so appealing. Throw a lot of bait in the water in phase one and then phase two, once you have a fish on the line, is the dude under the bridge. Having just read the wiki entry, we're both right!

Comment: +1 for noting that its a fishing term, and not a reference to the creature.

Answer (score 4):

A quick scan of *Unwired* doesn't reveal any clues.

I'd suggest that "trolling" would go out of vogue. Meta-hate aside, most slang terms don't tend to last sixty years, and the net is a rapidly-changing miasma of new cultural memes.

Two suggestions:

- "Booshwashing": Bumping gums; talking about nothing useful.

(It's fun, and sort of themey IMHO, to borrow historical "gangster-era" slang. I think somebody else on rpg.se suggested this to me on a different question. Ex:
http://www.paper-dragon.com/1939/slang.html)

- "Milkfeed": Teen wannabe-netkiddie leeching off of their parents' MSP. Thinks they know it all. Someone who gets into arguments just to hear themself talk.

(It's always fun to make up your own, too.)

- "eThug": Nerd who thinks they're a bada** on the 'trix.

(My brother made this one up, referring to the modern internet.)

Comment: Here's the thing...I don't know another word for trolling. I think it's really a new definition tacked onto an existing word for the modern age. Heck I can't even come up with a single word synonym for bad public behavior in an internet community.

Comment: Trolling as a term has lasted (at least) 17 years so far. Practically forever in "public internet access" terms.

Answer (score 2):

I would classify this as "Slotting/Slotting Off" to borrow from the phrase "Slot off, frag face!" from Shadowrun for the Sega Genesis/Mega Drive.
This could be used as an accusation like

> "Are you slotting (with) me?"

Comment: Its a decent choice... "Slotting around my MoSoSo" --- I kinda always imagined "Slot" as a f-word replacement though, so it fits, but it still fits a TON of things... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Griefing is an analogous term from computer gaming slang, I'm sure by whatever time Shadowrun is set, that word could have caught hold for forum abuse as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the world of SR I would think that "Jacking" would be a good slur especially with the undertones and the reference to hijacking a thread, and pun on the datajacks.

Comment: Not to mention FastJack for in the know old timers.

Comment: "Jacking" seems to "open" of a term for that type of behavior